# Prevent iframe keyboard event from scrolling the holding page

Tags: jquery, html

After significant bit of research (here and elsewhere) I've found a way to prevent keyboard presses to scroll the HTML page:

```
var ar=new Array(33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40);
var prevent_acc = function(e) {                    
     var key = e.which;
      console.log(key);
      //if(key==35 || key == 36 || key == 37 || key == 39)
      if($.inArray(key,ar) > -1) {
          console.log("preventing")
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
      return true;                
}

$(document).keydown(prevent_acc);
$(document).keyup(prevent_acc);                
$(document).keypress(prevent_acc);
```

It all works well when the focus is on the main page. However, I have a problem when an iframe container gets focus - then, the whole page gets scrolled and the function is not triggered.

Do I need to insert some code into each of the iframes or is there a way to catch an event bubbling up from it and prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good solution is to listen for the focus to happen and then change it as a result... so

```
$('iFrame').click(function(){
 window.focus();
});
```

This will still let the click inside of the iframe happen but returns the focus back to your window right after.

Comment: The problem is that we actually need the iFrame to have focus - there is a game which uses arrow and other keys inside of it..